# String to Custom DateTime Format Parse C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime-format

I have a string like this

```
"10/22/2012 9:13:15 PM".
```

I want to parse it to `DateTime` Format like this format

```
"2012-10-22T21:13:15+00:00"
```

This is my code.

```
string startTime = "10/22/2012 9:13:15 PM";

Datetime date = DateTime.ParseExact(
  startTime, 
 "yyyy’-‘MM’-‘dd’T’HH’:’mm’:’ss.fffffffK", 
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
  DateTimeStyles.None);
```

But it generates this exception.

> System.FormatException: String '10/22/2012 5:00:00 PM' was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

How to solve it?

Comment: Your format specifies all characters that MUST be in the string. Your string input must look like `"2012’-‘10’-‘20’T’09’:’13’:’15.fffffffK"` ... and whatever fffffffK is - look UP the format strings and fix it to suit your given input.

Comment: When it's a `DateTime`, it *doesn't have a format*. It instead is just wrapping an integer counting the number of 100ns intervals since its epoch date. Don't confuse *data* with *presentation*.

Answer (score 3):

You should `ParseExact` `string` into `date` using *existing* format:

```
string startTime = "10/22/2012 9:13:15 PM";
  
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(
  startTime, 
 "M/d/yyyy h:m:s tt", // <- given format 
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
  DateTimeStyles.None);
```

And only then format the `date` while using *desired* format:

```
// format we want
var result = date.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.fffffffK");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use DateTime.Parse instead of DateTime.ParseExact

here is code

```
string dateInput = "10/22/2012 9:13:15 PM";
var parsedDate = DateTime.Parse(dateInput);
```

Comment: Note, that `Parse` uses `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` which vary from workstation to workstation, so your solution will work on some computers only